# How to find as much and complete as possible partition of a list?

Tags: python

For example:

```
list1 = [5,8]
list2 = [4,4,2,3,6]
```

It is easy to get the combination of 5 and 8 in `list2` by using [powerset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) function

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

8 can be comprised of `[4,4]` or `[2,6]`,  but 5 can only be comprised of `[2,3]`. If I choose `[2,6]` for 8 , there is no combination for 5 in `list2`.

How can I get `[4,4]` for 8 and `[2,3]` for 5?  I want to choose as much as possible combinations in `list2` for the numbers in `list1`. Actually the numbers in `list1` may be comprised of 3 or more numbers in `list2`.

The actual problem is more difficult, because may be there are some numbers not used in `list1` and the numbers in `list1` may be comprised of 3 or more numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
list1 = [5,8]
list2 = [4,4,2,3,6]


for i in list2:
    for j in list2:
        if i+j in list1:
            print("%d + %d = %d"%(i, j, i+j))
```

It tries to create every possible addition and if it's contained in the first list, output it.

Output:

```
4 + 4 = 8
4 + 4 = 8
4 + 4 = 8
4 + 4 = 8
2 + 3 = 5
2 + 6 = 8
3 + 2 = 5
6 + 2 = 8
```

Comment: what's with the dupes?

Comment: Thank you very much, but if [2,6] is chosen for 8, there is no possible combination left in list2 for 5, that is my problem. I want to choose as much as possible combinations in list2 for the numbers in list1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise and efficient way.

```
import itertools

def combos(a, b):

    matches = []
    for combo in list(itertools.combinations(a, 2)):
        if combo[0] + combo[1] in b:
            matches.append(combo)
return matches    

>> [(4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 6)]
```

Here is another way:

```
def foo(matches, *args):

    matches_dict = {k: [] for k in matches}
    for _, tup in enumerate(*args):
        if sum(tup) in matches:
            matches_dict[sum(tup)].append(tup)
    return matches_dict

>> {5: [(2, 3)], 8: [(4, 4), (2, 6)]}
```

Now timing them:

```
time combos(list2, list1)
CPU times: user 23 µs, sys: 7 µs, total: 30 µs
Wall time: 31 µs

time foo(list1, list(itertools.combinations(list2, 2)))
CPU times: user 33 µs, sys: 9 µs, total: 42 µs
Wall time: 40.1 µs
```

Using @moritzg answer, modified to not include dupes,

```
def fizz(list1, list2):
    matches = []
    for i in list2:
        for j in list2:
            if i+j in list1:
                matches.append((i,j))
    return set(matches)

time fizz(list1, list2)
CPU times: user 26 µs, sys: 13 µs, total: 39 µs
Wall time: 35 µs
```

Also I forgot to mention if for you `(2,6)` differs from `(6,2)` although it should not, you can switch `itertools.combinations` to `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but if [2,6] is chosen for 8, there is no possible combination left in list2 for 5, that is my problem. I want to choose as much as possible combinations in list2 for the numbers in list1.